# Detecting Overlapping objects in Paper JS

Tags: paperjs

One rectangle and a couple of circles are on canvas. Scattered. 
The circles which are on top of rectangle needs to be of different color.

Circle must be completely inside the rectangle.

How can I detect this in Paper JS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method [item.isInside(rectangle)](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#isinside-rect) seems to perfectly match your need.

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.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) demonstrating the solution.

```
// create 3 circles scattered on the canvas.
var circles = [
    new Path.Circle({
        center: view.center - 100,
        radius: 50,
        fillColor: 'orange'
    }),
    new Path.Circle({
        center: view.center,
        radius: 50,
        fillColor: 'orange'
    }),
    new Path.Circle({
        center: view.center + 150,
        radius: 50,
        fillColor: 'orange'
    })
];

// Create a rectangle.
var rectangle = new Path.Rectangle({
    from: view.center - 80,
    to: view.center + 80,
    strokeColor: 'black'
});

// Scale things up so that we can see better.
project.activeLayer.fitBounds(view.bounds.scale(0.8));

// For each circle...
circles.forEach(circle => {
    // ...if circle is contained in rectangle bounds...
    if (circle.isInside(rectangle.bounds)) {
        // ...change circle color.
        circle.fillColor = 'blue';
    }
});
```

Comment: You are awesome! this is exactly what I was looking for. 
I tried to find on documentation and just missed it. 

Thanks @sasensi. You Rock!